# Sensors - device coordinate system vs world frame coordinate system

Tags: android, machine-learning, accelerometer, android-sensors, coordinate-systems

I am collecting accelerometer and gyroscope data from an Android smartwatch while being in **a moving car.**

The goal is to be able to classify, using Hidden Markov Modelss, whether the subjects are the driver of the car of a passenger, looking at e.g. the steering wheel.

When reading about android sensors, i noticed the following statement:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

> When a device is held in its default orientation, the X axis is horizontal and points to the right, the Y axis is vertical and points up, and the Z axis points toward the outside of the screen face.

As i interpret it: The axes of (x, y, z) from an accelerometer and a gyroscope will swap according to the orientation of the device. I've read that it is possible to fix the three axis to the world frame coordinate system, so for example Z axis always measures vertical acceleration from an accerometer.

Opposed to if the axes are not fixed, I think the data will generalize poorly for a classification purpose. **However**, I am uncertatain whether it is an issue, or if data where axes are not fixed is equally good or better.

A sub question is whether there are other sensors than accelerometer gyroscope which could be used for this classification goal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems like such a complicated question that it might be suited for a different site, or be a good candidate for a bounty. The fact that the phone could be in many orientations relative to the car would mean you would have to somehow account for that, despite not having a fixed frame of reference to work with.